# Does method for plotting need return?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a class with methods to build some plots. I try to display different plots on one figure. The properties (title, legend...) of the figure are always overwritten by the last plot. I expected that if I have `return` in my method the behaviour would be different to the method without it, but it seems to not be true.

I would like to figure out what difference makes to have `return`. The code to illustrate my question is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class myClass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.random.random(100)
        self.y = np.random.random(100)

    def plotNReturn1(self):
        plt.plot(self.x,self.y,'-*',label='randNxy')
        plt.title('Plot No Return1')
        plt.legend(numpoints = 1)
    def plotNReturn2(self):
        plt.plot(self.y,self.x,'-x',label='randNzw')
        plt.title('Plot No Return2')
        plt.legend(numpoints = 2)

    def plotWReturn1(self):
        fig = plt.plot(self.x,self.y,'-*',label='randWxy')
        fig = plt.title('Plot With Return1')
        fig = plt.legend(numpoints = 1)
        return fig
    def plotWReturn2(self):
        fig = plt.plot(self.y,self.x,'-x',label='randWzw')
        fig = plt.title('Plot With Return2')
        plt.legend(numpoints = 3)
        return fig


if __name__=='__main__':
    f = myClass1()
    p = plt.figure()

    p1 = p.add_subplot(122)
    p1 = f.plotWReturn1()
    p1 = f.plotWReturn2()
    print 'method with return: %s: ' % type(p1)

    p2 = p.add_subplot(121)
    p2 = f.plotNReturn1()
    p2 = f.plotNReturn2()
    print 'method without return: %s: ' % type(p2)

    plt.show()
```

The only difference I noticed is the type of the output, but I don't know what it means in practice.

```
 method with return: <class 'matplotlib.text.Text'>: 
 method without return: <type 'NoneType'>:
```

Is it only about "pythonic" practice or is there anything practical to use any of the style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a value has only a direct effect for the caller, in this case your `__main__` block. If you don't need to reuse some value computed by a function, in your case assigned to p1 or p2, the return doesn't have any impact on behaviour.

Also, series of assignments like

```
p1 = call1()
p1 = call2()
p1 = call3()
```

are indicators of bad code style, because only the last value assigned to p1 is going to be available after them.

Anyway, I think you want to plot on subplots, as opposed to the main plot, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class myClass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.random.random(100)
        self.y = np.random.random(100)

    def plotNReturn1(self, subplot):
        subplot.plot(self.x,self.y,'-*',label='randNxy')
        subplot.set_title('Plot No Return1')
        subplot.legend(numpoints = 1)
    def plotNReturn2(self, subplot):
        subplot.plot(self.y,self.x,'-x',label='randNzw')
        subplot.set_title('Plot No Return2')
        subplot.legend(numpoints = 2)


if __name__=='__main__':
    f = myClass1()
    p = plt.figure()

    p1 = p.add_subplot(122)
    f.plotNReturn2(p1)

    p2 = p.add_subplot(121)
    f.plotNReturn2(p2)

    plt.show()
```

Here, subplot is passed to each function, so data should be plotted on it, instead of replacing what you've plotted before.

Answer (score 2):

Python functions return `None` if they don't have a return statement.  Otherwise, they return whatever you tell them to.

In terms of conventions, if a function operates on the arguments passed to it, it is polite to have that function return `None`.  That way, the user knows that the arguments were messed with.  (an example of this is `list.append` -- It modifies the list and returns `None`).

```
a = [1,2,3]
print a.append(4) #None
print a #[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you're function isn't going to mess with the stuff passed to it, then it's useful to have it return something:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, thanks. In method which should display some plots is there any point to use `return`?

Comment: @tomasz74 -- If the purpose is to *display* the plots, I would have it return `None` to indicate that you're calling the function for side-effects.